# "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.Tq @ VM107:37mF , when gmap is adding

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am newbie, practicing html and jquery. 
Could any one please help me resolving this error? 
when i was try to add google map dynamically, i was getting an error like Uncaught typeError: failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'window': parameter.

html markup is:

```
<type="submit" id="locate">Find me</button>
<div id="gmap"> </div>

enter code here

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#locate').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
            }
        });
        var latlng,
         mapOptions,
         map;

        showPosition = function (position) {
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            mapOptions = {
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 15
            }
            Map = new google.maps.Map($('#gmap'), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "You are here"
            })
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 14):

Two issues:

1. JavaScript is case-sensitive, this line:

   ```
   Map = new google.maps.Map
   ```

   should be

   ```
   map = new google.maps.Map
   ```

   (Note the lower case m in the map at the beginning.)

   So why weren't you getting an "undefined variable" error or something? Because of [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Consider using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) so you get proactive notifications instead.
2. The `google.maps.Map` constructor expects you to give it an *element* as its first argument, but you're not doing that. You're giving it a jQuery object:

   ```
   map = new google.maps.Map($('#gmap'), mapOptions);
   //                        ^^^^^^^^^^--- this is a jQuery object
   ```

   To get the only element inside the jQuery object, use `[0]`:

   ```
   map = new google.maps.Map($('#gmap')[0], mapOptions);
   // Here ----------------------------^^^
   ```

Comment: @KusumaRr: Good deal. Note: The `@` notation is for notifying *other* people of your comment, you wouldn't use it with your own name.

Comment: Using the insertion of `[0]` worked for me as I was selecting it by class name instead of ID name.